# Cakephp with Rackspace cloud database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I'm thinking about moving one of my clients mysql db to Rackspace could databases. Application is using Cakephp.. I would like to know if someone has experience doing so or will this work just by editing host/user/pass in the database.php file?

Comment: Consider searching before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havn't done so but Rackspace has a tutorial about doing so :

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-cakephp-on-cloud-sites

It seems pretty simple, so you should not have any problems

> ## Steps for cake
>
> 1. Locate the .htaccess file in the content directory. After "RewriteEngine on", add a new line with "RewriteBase /" to the .htaccess file and save the file back to the site. You will need to repeat this step for the rewrite rules in the .htaccess files in the app and app/webroot directories.
> 2. Load the site in your browser. You will notice several warnings concerning the installation. The first warning will be the following: Notice (1024): Please change the value of Security.salt in app/config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application [CORE/cake/libs/debugger.php, line 556].
> 3. Open app/config/core.php file and search for Security.salt. Change its value to whatever characters or string you would like, then save and close the file.
> 4. In the app/config/directory in FTP, rename the database.php.default file to be database.php.
> 5. Open app/config/database.php and scroll down to the bottom of the page to find the database connection information. Enter your database host name, user name, password and hostname, then save and close the file.
> 6. Reload your site in your browser.

Comment: How can I hide index.php from URL? Applied all above changes to Rackspace cakephp set up